# Can I safely connect audio out to audio in with an aux cable?

Tags: audio, desktop-computer, audio-recording, audio-conversion, digital-audio

This question might be really dumb. But can I safely connect the audio output from one pc to the audio/microphone input on another pc, using an aux cable? I want to record audio from one pc on another pc using audacity.
What I mean by "safe" is like will it short out or anything crazy? Also can I connect the audio out to the audio in on the same pc without problems? I know sound is just a wave, but I don't know if that applies here.

Forgive me, if this is the wrong fourm for this question, or if this question is really stupid.

This is just a random image I found online. However, just in case I don't know the proper names, these are the ports I'm talking about.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Hij.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only stupid question is the one you don't ask.
There. You're off THAT hook. ;-)

Audio Out on PC1 to Audio In on PC2 is a perfectly reasonable thing to do and won't harm anything. If the PCs have Line In and Line Out connections, those will likely provide better results.

But in many cases you can record from PC1's sound output directly to Audacity running on PC1. No need for a second computer.

https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html

Comment: Okay thank you so much for the clarification, I thought it might've sounded dumb like the infinite power memes with the power strip plugged into itself. I also just wanted to stay on the safe side, and avoid damaging anything until I knew for sure. Again, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Random9392 LOL! I actually knew a guy online who got called out on a tech call (at a hefty hourly rate) to "fix" a computer that was plugged in. To the power strip on the crash cart. That was plugged in. To the power strip on the crash cart.